# TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined in the switch(action.type)

Tags: reactjs, redux

I tried to follow video from youtube about redux for the first time but cant figure out why i got `undefined`. I already trying to Google for the answer but still cant figure it out.

```
 import { createStore } from 'redux';


  //action
  const up = () => {
    return { 
      type: 'up' 
    }
  }

  const down = () => {
    return { 
      type: 'down' 
    }
  }

  //reducer
  const counter = (state = 0, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
      case 'up':
        return state + 1;
      case 'down':
        return state - 1;
    }
  }
        
  let store = createStore(counter());

  store.subscribe(() => console.log(store.getState()))

  store.dispatch(up())
  store.dispatch(down())
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You must pass the actual function in ```createStore``` like this: ```createStore(counter)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass the actual function in `createStore` like this:

```
  let store = createStore(counter);
```

This way, you are passing the actual function definition of `counter`, not just returning the state.

Comment: you mean this code let store = createStore(counter()); ? i'm creating error there?

Comment: Yes. Replace it with ```let store = createStore(counter)```

Comment: btw, how to show the value of state inside component?

Comment: If you are using a functional component, you might want to use ```useSelector``` hook (https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks)